# IronRuby and C#, Execute File

Tags: c#, ironruby

Why this work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using IronRuby;

class Tutorial
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
       engine.Runtime.Globals.SetVariable("Holly",new Holly("Test"));
       engine.Execute("Holly.Say");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
class Holly
{
   string speech;
   public Holly(string speech)
   {
       this.speech = speech;
   }
   public void Say()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hollu said " + this.speech);
   }
}
```

and this is not work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using IronRuby;

class Tutorial
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
       engine.Runtime.Globals.SetVariable("Mouse",new Holly("Test"));
       engine.ExecuteFile("./test.rb");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
class Holly
{
   string speech;
   public Holly(string speech)
   {
       this.speech = speech;
   }
   public void Say()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hollu said " + this.speech);
   }
}
```

Comment: My first guess is that `./test.rb` is not found - what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
engine.ExecuteFile(@"..\test.rb");
```

Also wrap your code in try/catch statement and check for exception

```
try
{
    var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
    engine.Runtime.Globals.SetVariable("Holly",new Holly("Test"));
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"..\test.rb");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: engine.ExecuteFile(@"..\test.rb"); Not work. Exception: NoImplementedException

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585047/returning-a-clr-type-from-ironruby

Can you also try to specify full pass to your test.rb file.  Such as engine.ExecuteFile(@"c:\test\test.rb");