# Can't Convert X::Y::Z to X::Y::Z in IronRuby

Tags: c#, ironruby

I'm playing around with IronRuby. I made the stubs of an interactive fiction game. In C#, I have a `Command` class which represents a command (name, text to type, and action delegate):

public delegate string CommandAction(string target, string instrument, string preposition);
        private CommandAction action;

```
    public Command(string name, string[] verbs, CommandAction action)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Verbs = verbs;
        this.action = action;
    }
```

I create commands in C# without any problem. Here's the simplest:

```
this.knownCommands.Add(new Command("Quit", new string[] { "q", "quit" }, (t, i, p) =>
{
    isRunning = false;
    return "Bye!";
}));
```

(Don't worry about the three parameters right now, they're all strings.)

I want to make a command and add it to my `IEnumerable<Command>` list. Here's the Ruby code:

```
def to_clr_string_array(list)
    System::Array[System::String].new(list.map { |s| s.to_s.to_clr_string })
end

require 'Meltdown.Core.dll'
include Meltdown::Core

Command.new("Ruby Command", to_clr_string_array(['rb']), Proc.new { |target, preposition, instrument|
    puts "Command invoked with #{target}, #{instrument}, and #{preposition}"
})
```

(`to_clr_string_array` is necessary to convert list types.) When I try to instantiate this, I get a type conversion error: `Can't Convert Meltdown::Core::Command into Meltdown::Core::Command`. Here's how I do it:

```
var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
var scope = Engine.Runtime.CreateScope();
string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(scriptPath);
var command = engine.Execute<Command>(contents, scope);
```

The third line fails. I tried [this answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592949/210780), coupled with changing my array into a list of objects. Instead of the instantiation failing, when I execute the command, I get an error that the types are different.

In that detailed error, it mentions exactly the same error as the question in the answer I linked: the types differ only in their context (`Default` and `LoadNeither`).

Unfortunately, that doesn't help me, and I still can't figure out how to do this. I've tried also passing my list of commands into Ruby, but I get an error that the types don't match and it can't go into my list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question to the ironruby-core mailing list. Brandon Doot replied and suggested I add:

`load_assembly 'SharedClasses'`

This solved the problem. The types are now the same as far as .NET is concerned.